# How to bind the event handler of socket.io (in nodejs) to my own scope?

Tags: javascript, events, scope, node.js, socket.io

I'm using "socket.io" in my nodejs server. Is there a way to run the registered event functions in the scope of my class/module (in the browser)?

```
...
init: function() {
  this.socket = new io.Socket('localhost:3000'); //connect to localhost presently
  this.socket.on('connect', this.myConnect);
},
myConnect: function() {
  // "this.socket" and "this.f" are unknown
  // this.socket.send({});
  // this.f();
},
f: function() {
  // ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I *think* V8 supports the "bind()" function:

```
this.socket.on('connect', this.myConnect.bind(this));
```

The call to "bind" will return a function that will call *your* function such that `this` is set to the argument you pass (in this case, `this` from the context of the call to that "init" function).

*edit* — "bind()" is there in the Function prototype in Chrome, so I imagine it works fine in node.

Here's what you can try in a browser (one that's got the function available, like Chrome):

```
 var f = (function() { alert(this); }).bind("hello world");
 f();
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no Chrome to test it and it doesn't work in Firefox. Is there an other way?

Comment: Also you should really try Chrome - it's a nice browser and very fast :-)

Comment: May be but I know users that are still using IE6. I can't order it.

Comment: But you said you were using socket.io in your nodejs **server** - now you're saying that it's client-side code that needs this?

Comment: I meant "with". So I use it on the server and on the client.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it in my YUI3 context with

```
this.socket.on('connect', Y.bind(this.myConnect, this));
```

Thanks to Pointy for the word "bind".