# How to add or bind dynamic function handlers to socket.io events like express routes with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, routes, socket.io

My requirement is to add dynamically the handler of socket.io events.

For example with express I can do this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var functions = []
functions.push({route:"/foo", definition: function(req, res) {
  res.type('text/plain');
  res.send('Hell , its about time!!');
}})

for(var _function of functions){
  app.get(_function.route, _function.definition);
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

But with socket.io is not possible because we need to attach or bind the handlers **after the connection event**. Check this working sample:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //this line is executed only when client is connected
  //inside the connection event
  socket.on('input', async function (data) {
      console.log(data)
  });
});
```

### Attempt #0

I tried this. It starts but the **input** event is never received in the server

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("headers at connection:")
  console.log(socket.handshake.headers)
});

io.on('input', async function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
});
```

### Attempt #1

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7 })

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //binding starts here
  socket.on('input', function (data) {
    doit(data, socket, io.sockets);
  });
});

function doit(data, currentSocket, globalSocket) {
  //do whatever you want
}


console.log("Running on port: " + 3000)
```

But the line **//binding starts here** is not executed at launch (npm run start). It is executed at runtime, when the connection is established.

### Attempt #2

Read the docs https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/ but I only found about custom namespaces.

### Next attempt

I will try **socketio-wildcard** but since I will need to receive files, I don't know if this implementation will work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47458589/3957754

Anyway, is not so clean like my approach with express and simple http routes.

### Question

How to add dynamic handlers to socket.io events like express routes?

I mean, how to binding the event handlers outside the connection event. I need to binding before that. Something similar to my **Attempt #0**

### Similar questions

- [How to bind the event handler of socket.io (in nodejs) to my own scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221978/how-to-bind-the-event-handler-of-socket-io-in-nodejs-to-my-own-scope)
- [How to access the target socket in a Socket.io handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380642/how-to-access-the-target-socket-in-a-socket-io-handler)
- [Socket.IO and express routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630619/socket-io-and-express-routes)